# Install JetEntityFrameWorkProvider on Visual Studio 2019 for C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2019, jet-ef-provider

I want to develope one application in C# under Visual Studio and I pretend to use Entity Framework with two Access DBs (with accdb extension). I found the JetEntityFrameworkProvider project developed by 
Umberto Ballestrazzi(Alias Bubi), I saw the video which explain all the process to get working on Visual Studio but I don't get It. One of the steps requires to Download and Compile the project, but the pre and post compile commands fail with the following messages:

Error       Command "call "D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
gacutil /u JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll" exited with  code 9009.  Project: JetDdexProvider.

Error       Command ""%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u "JetEntityFrameworkProvider"" exited with code 3. Project: JetEntityFrameworkProvider.

Following the video indications I've Downloaded JetEntityFrameWorkProvider and DDEX-Deserialiser Nugets. I've manually added the machine.config entry, I've changed vsvars32.bat to vsdevcmd.bat as some other threads suggested and I don't get to progress.

How can I get to work it in order to create and EDMX diagram with Access Provider?
Can I use It with Access versions 2007 or 2010, MDBs and ACCDBs?

Things to keep in care:

- I want to use with Visual Studio 2019, all solutions I found where for Visual Studio Community 2017 or before, If there's no more way i could Downgrade to 2017 if that could solve the problem, but I prefer to use 2019.
- I've downloaded JetEntityFrameWorkProvider Version 6.2.0-rc1 and DDEX-Deserialiser Version 3.7.0 Nugets.
- I've followed the indications of this link posted by Bubi to explain the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHrpY_nMXrk

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is it an option to convert the Access database into Sql Server?

Comment: I'm afraid no. The project requisites are to use an Access Database.

Answer (score 0):

Go to NuGet packages and search fore JetEntityFramework
when you install it all you need is to add to your app.config file this connection string

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="Baza" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test.accdb" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
```

D:\test.accdb is the location of the file if you want to be in the directory the same as your app just use |DataDirectory|\test.accdb works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [visual-studio-201x-version](https://github.com/aspdotnetgabs/sharpdevelopmvc/tree/visual-studio-201x-version)

of this repo https://github.com/aspdotnetgabs/sharpdevelopmvc. It has all the things you need to use **JetEntityFrameworkProvider** for Entity Framework 6.

It already has the following:

**packages.config**

```
<package id="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" version="6.2.0-rc1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

**csproj**

```
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

**web.config**

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="v13.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />           
        <provider invariantName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderServices, JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Jet Entity Framework Provider" invariant="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" description="Jet Entity Framework Provider" type="JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetProviderFactory, JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

**Connection String**

```
<add name="MyAccessDb" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyAccessDb.mdb" providerName="JetEntityFrameworkProvider" />
```

***and a pre-configured/tweak blank MDB file***

```
/App_Data/MyAccessDb.mdb
```

I created this template project in Visual Studio 2019 so I think you are good to go.